# Bayes Rule Bayesian Risk and Decision

Tags: self-study, bayesian, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

Good day,

When attempting this problem I came across some difficulties.

> A humanitarian charity wishes to classify a village as being at either high or low risk of flooding. The following historical data on the number of weeks between successive floods is collected:
>   $$Y_1 = 2.65, Y_2 = 3.07$$
>   Let $\theta$ denote the risk status of the village.
>
> - If  $\theta$=0 then the village is low risk and the $Y_i$ are independent from an $Exp(0.5)$ distribution.
> - If  $\theta= 1$ then the village is high risk and the $Y_i$ are independent from an $Exp(1)$ distribution.
>
> Both scenarios are considered equally likely prior to collecting the historical data.
>
> Let action $a_0$ correspond to classifying the village as low risk, and action $a_1$ as high risk.
>
> Assume the losses from misclassication are $L(a_0, \theta = 1) = 5, L(a_1, \theta = 0) = 1, L(a_0, \theta = 0) = 0, L(a1, \theta = 1) = 0$
>
> Find the risk associated with both actions, and hence state how the village should be classied.

So, from this I get that the prior would simply be $p(\theta = 0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $p(\theta = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$.

The loss matrix is

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a_i&\theta=0&\theta=1   \\ \hline
 a_0&0 & 5\\ \hline
 a_1&1 &0\\ \hline
\end{array}

The question also says that $Y|\theta=0$ follows a $Exp(0.5)$ distribution and $Y|\theta=1$ follows a $Exp(1)$.

I am not quite sure where to go from here as when I tried finding $p(y)$ to use in Bayes Rule, I get a different answer to the solutions (the solutions do not explain how to get the answer).

Comment: please add the `self-study` tag

Comment: **Hint #1:** you need to minimise the posterior expected loss, which does not require $p(y_1,y_2)$ if I read your notations correctly

Comment: I found the solution using $P(Y_1,Y_2|\theta)=P(Y_1|\theta)*P(Y_2| \theta)$. And used this to find $P(Y)$